# Missing Option to Save Documents and Settings - USB Startup Disk

Tags: 16.04, startup-disk-creator

The 16.04 Startup Disk Creator no longer has the option to disable saving documents and settings in reserved extra space.  Note the option visible on the right and missing on the left.

[image: Step 5 - How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu]
From: [How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Does a Ubuntu 16.04 USB Startup Disk save documents and settings by default?  If so, how do I disable?  If not, how do I enable?

Comment: I don't want to be forced to have a write-partition for my Live sticks. I use them to show Ubuntu to friends, and a readonly live stick is 4-5 faster in boot than a writeable dito, which is just really annoying so I always disable the "feature" of saving apps' and docs' to the stick.

Comment: @OlofBjarnason. I didn't understand. What is the relation of your comment with the question? You want that he use only to show to friends?

Comment: I wanted to add to the question, that having the ability to disable "write partition" is good from performance/boot time perspective. And that is an important use case for prospective/new Ubuntu Linux users - getting the first impression of Ubuntu being extremely slow to boot is not nice.

Comment: this is answered here askubuntu.com/questions/772093/where-is-the-persistent-option-for-startup-disk-creator-in-16-04